# Unable to enter decimal in jTextField cause of restricted to enter character

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I've restricted user to enter character in     `jTextField` but that doesn't let enter decimal.

```
char price = evt.getKeyChar();
        if (!Character.isDigit(price)
                || (price == KeyEvent.VK_BACKSPACE)
                || (price == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {
            evt.consume();
        }
```

After adding this code to     `jTextFieldKyeTyped()` event it does let me enter only digits but not decimals.

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JFormattedField instead of character filtering. Check that working code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.InternationalFormatter;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
        format.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        format.setMaximumFractionDigits(5);
        format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        InternationalFormatter formatter = new InternationalFormatter(format);
        formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);

        JFormattedTextField field = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(field);
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working thanks so may I need to replace     `jTextField` with   
  `jFormattedTextField`

Comment: It has few more not mentioned in my example configuration options. Check them out.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 char price = evt.getKeyChar();
            if ((!Character.isDigit(price)
                    || (price == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                    || (price == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))
                    && (price!='.')){
                evt.consume();
            }
            if(price=='.'&&textField.getText().contains('.'+"")){
                evt.consume();
            }
```

Comment: @tomerpacific look at the code again please, I did this already.

Comment: This code doesn't working.

Comment: You probably forgot the round brackets before the &&. It has to be this way:
if((1st||2nd||3rd)&&(4th||5th){ . In this case the numbers are standing for the conditions. This code definitly works.

Comment: Ok I'll check it again. But now I've changed with jFormattedTextField.

Comment: It is also working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the field to numerical values, consider using `JSpinner` class instead of `JTextField`. You can configure it like this:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 1000, 0.01));
```

(In this example minimum value = 0, maximum value = 1000, step size = 0.01)